How do I use the URI of a GCP Cloud Run resource in an environment variable for the same resource?
I'm deploying a container via Google Cloud Run and would like to pass the public URI to an environment variable for the resource. How can I do this without running multiple passes of terraform apply or depending upon outside executables (if I'm using some sort of Terraform automation)?
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "cr_myapp" {
  name     = "myapp"
  location = "us-central1"
  ingress  = "INGRESS_TRAFFIC_ALL"

  template {
    service_account = module.service_account.email

    containers {
      image = "myapp:${var.myapp_version}"

      # added variable
      env {
        name  = "PUBLIC_URL"
        value = google_cloud_run_v2_service.cr_myapp.uri # <-- this is wrong because it creates a circular dependency
      }
    }
  }
}


This is likely an anti-pattern and discouraged. The URI is exported by google_cloud_run_v2_service as one of the Attributes and so can be used in other Terraform commands.

The Attributes correspond to the underlying API v2 Service and accessible as the uri which can be accessed anywhere else you need it.

Since the Service's URI is accessible and constant, it is redundant (and potentially problematic) to duplicate it as an environment variable. Not duplicating it, solves your problem too as you can access the value (as described above).

The issue here is I am using a third-party container from Docker Hub that needs this publc URL to be provided as an ENV variable in order to be correctly configured. Obviously since this is a container it's not cognizant of its underlying cloud infrastructure.

I've attempted using a "null_resource" with a "local-exec" provisioner to grab the URI and save it to a file, but since I'm using other third-party automation to run terraform I don't have the gcloud executable to set the ENV variable after the fact.

This value can be computed, for example, when the instance start and put in global variable to be used all the Cloud Run instance lifecycle.
I wrote an article where you can find piece of code where I get the URL of the current instance.

Another solution is to put the Cloud Run service behind a load balancer. This time, because you manage the Load Balancer configuration and the domain name, you totally manage the Cloud Run service URL through a public name server.

Finally a future solution, only in private preview for a few testers like me, will be the "predictable URL" feature: a defined pattern that combine the service name, project ID and region to let you now in advance the URL to reach.
